# how to execute bash script from python (bash file contains user input)

Tags: python

i need a python script which connect to my server (openstack) via ssh and then there is a bash file demo-openrc.sh (this bash script needs to be excuted first and then i will run my following commands like openstack server list (it will return my all instance's)) but the problem is that the bash script contains the enviroment variable and there is 1 user input for openstack project how can i take this bash enviroment variable input from user in python

```
from _multiprocessing import send

import paramiko
import cmd
import time
import sys
import os
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE


from paramiko import SSHClient
host="172.17.85.250"
user="stack"
passs="salman"
client = SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.connect(hostname=host, username=user , password=passs)
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('./demo-openrc.sh')
print ("stderr: ", stderr.readlines())
print ("pwd: ", stdout.readlines())
```

Comment: paramiko will not give you a login bash. in login bash you can source your environment variables. So, append 'sudo -i' to the command you want to run. client.exec_command(' sudo -i ./demo-openrc.sh')

Comment: @Ajay2588 in demo-openrc.sh there is almost 10 enviroment variables but 1 need user input which is basically a password but the problem is that when i source this .sh file -->In terminal-please enter your password but it does not take user input and execute the next command is there any way how to resolve it thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, got your problem. You have to use module `subprocess` and use communicate function to communicate user input to the respective function. `subprocess.communicate` will send user input to the sub process that has been created by subprocess modeul itself. Check this code bit below. This peace of code is passing input "Ajay" to the test.sh script. This is a logic and an attempt to show you how things be done.

In your case, create a python script on a remote machine which does sourcing the bash script and from python script, you can pass on the input to the bash script

### test.sh

> /bin/bash
>
> read -p "Enter Your Name: "  username
>
> echo "Welcome $username!"

### Python script - written in python3.7

> import subprocess
>
> process = subprocess.Popen(['bash', 'test.sh'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
> stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>
> out, error = process.communicate(b'Ajay')
>
> print(out)

**Output**

b'Welcome Ajay!\n'

Comment: If that helped, then accept the solution as answer. And thanks for your wish :)